# I am getting DefaultviewUrl error in CEWP SharePoint 2013 while trying to display document libraries

Tags: 2013

I am trying to display document libraries links in Content Editor Web Part using Jquery, which worked without any issues in SharePoint 2010. But in SharePoint 2013 I am getting the below error:

> The property or field 'DefaultViewUrl' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Can some one help me out on what I am doing wrong?

```
<link href="/Test/Applications/SiteAssets/style/Table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/Test/Applications/SiteAssets/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Test/Applications/SiteAssets/jQuery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Test/Applications/SiteAssets/jQuery/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Test/Applications/SiteAssets/jQuery/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Test/Applications/SiteAssets/jQuery/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Test/Applications/TestReleases/SiteAssets/JavaScript/security.js"></script>
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Test/Applications/TestReleases/SiteAssets/style/customMenu.css" />
<script src="/Test/Applications/SiteAssets/JavaScript/ApplicationManagedServices.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Test/Applications/SiteAssets/style/controls-6E924A6.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

    var _clientContext = null;
    var _web = null;
    var _sitefullURL = null;
    var collList  = null;
    var txt = null;
    var _currentUser = null;
    var staffList = null;
    var staffListCollItems = null;
    var itemOrg = null;

    var orgList = null;
    var orgListCollItems = null;
    var itemAMSTeam = null;

 function initForm() {


        getUserInformation().done(function (userOb) {
            loggedinUserName = userOb.get_title();
            loggedinUserEmail = userOb.get_email();
            _currUserID = userOb.get_id();

            _clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

            _web = _clientContext.get_web();
            _sitefullURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _clientContext.get_url();
            ShowProgressAnimation();
            //getUserOrganization();
            //getListCollection();
                    getListCollection();
            $.when( getUserOrganization() ).done(function() {
                $.when( getAMSTeam() ).done(function() {

                    var itemTxt = document.getElementById('teamID');
                    itemTxt.innerHTML = itemAMSTeam;
                    setMenu();
                });
            });

        });
    }


 function getListCollection() {
        try {

            collList = _web.get_lists();
            _clientContext.load(collList);
            _clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { onQuerySucceeded(); }, function () { onQueryFailed(); });

        }
        catch (Error) {
            alert(Error.message);
        }



        function onQuerySucceeded(){
            var count = this.collList.get_count();
            var hiddenItems = ["Documents", "Images", "Pages", "Site Assets", "Site Pages", "Master Page Gallery"];

            //Loop through results and build table rows

                        var itemList = document.getElementById("ulMainGroup");
                        //getChildT("Home-icon.png",itemList, 'Home', '/Test/Applications/');
            createLinkCustom("Home-icon.png",itemList, 'Home', '/Test/Applications/');
            for (var x = 0; x < count ; x++) {
                         var title = this.collList.itemAt(x).get_title();
                           if(this.collList.itemAt(x).get_baseType() == 1 && findIndex(hiddenItems, title)  == -1){
                                if(title == 'Training Documents'){
                    createLinkCustom("dev_icon.png",itemList, this.collList.itemAt(x).get_title(), this.collList.itemAt(x).get_defaultViewUrl());
                                }else
                    {

                    createLinkCustom("Blank-Folder-icon.png",itemList, this.collList.itemAt(x).get_title(), this.collList.itemAt(x).get_defaultViewUrl()); //Blank-Folder-icon.png
                                }
               }
            }

            createLinkCustom("orange-add-list-48.png",itemList, 'Tasks', '/Test/Applications/TestReleases/Lists/Tasks/');
            createLinkCustom("orange-add-list-48.png",itemList, 'Schedules', '/Test/Applications/TestReleases/Lists/Schedules/');

            HideProgressAnimation();

        }

    function onQueryFailed() {alert(Error.message);}

}




    $(document).ready(function () {
        //ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(LoadSecurity, "sp.js");
/*
var liToMove = $('#zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 div>ul').html();
var fullmenu = "<ul class='root static'><li class='static'><a class='static menu-item' title='Home' href='/Test/Applications/' accesskey='1'><span class='additional-background'><span class='menu-item-text'>Dosumentation Trainings</span></span></a><ul class='static'>"+ liToMove + "</ul></li></ul>";

$('#zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4 div>ul').html(fullmenu);*/
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initForm, "sp.js");
        });
</script>
<table class ="mystyle"><tr><td><span id='idSpanText'></ span></td></tr></table>


<ul class="dfwp-column dfwp-list" style="width:100%" id="idMainMenu">
  <li class="dfwp-item">
    <div class="groupheader item medium" id="teamMainID">Menu</div>
    <ul class="dfwp-list" id='ulMainGroup'></ul>
</li>


</ul>

<div id="loading-div-background">
    <div id="loading-div"  >
      <img  src="/Test/Applications/SiteAssets/ajax-loader%20(1).gif" alt="Loading.."/>
      <h2 style="color:gray;font-weight:normal;">Please wait....</h2>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Hi Shashank posted above.